# How to modify a child id using the parent id?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick, parent-child

For some background, I have a set of graphs that show data for one country (e.g. England). I'd like to be able to update all of these graphs to show data for a different country (e.g. Scotland) at the press of a button.

The way I'm currently trying to do it, is by finding the parent ID and then changing the child ID (this seems much faster than doing an IF statement to check what the child ID is, and then changing it, because there's over 20 graphs).

My script so far:

```
document.getElementById("scotlandButton").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    $(document).find('#graph1-first-tab').find('#england_graph').attr('id', 'scotland_graph');
}
```

Html example:

```
<button id="scotlandButton">Scotland Data</button>

<div id="graph1-first-tab">
    <canvas id="england_graph"></canvas>
</div>
```

The graphs have IDs "england_graph" and "scotland_graph".

Thanks!

Comment: Everything works fine.

Comment: As far as I understand canvas should be rerendered after the change of id?

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with using canvas - how would I go about re-rendering the canvas without having to refresh the page?